# Understanding the asterisk "*" in functions/parameters

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand if there is any difference between:

```
bool String_Init(String *str, char * s, uint32_t len){};
```

and

```
bool String_Init(String *str, char *s, uint32_t len){};
```

Also,

```
const char * String_GetCString(const String * const str){};
```

and

```
const char *String_GetCString(const String * const str){};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Each pair are identical, first two and last two. Spaces does nothing.

Comment: I would flag it but the duplicate search is useless. I know it exists but I can't find it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Except the whitespace between the `*` and the parameter name, that's what confuses the OP I guess...

Comment: I wasn't able to find a similar question to mine. Most ppl were trying to understand pointers.

Comment: I have no idea why ppl are down voting this. Seriously, read the darn question before you down vote. I searched and found nothing.

Comment: Instead of asking all these incredibly basic questions, why don't you look it up in your C book? Or Google?

Comment: But you see mr @Lundin. That duplicate is different. They are talking about variables. I'm talking about functions. I'm new to C so I wouldn't know if the function and variable would be the same.

Comment: It is the very same thing. Function parameters are variables.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in more detail [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), for any type `T`, the expression `T*` means 'pointer to `T`'. It does not matter whether the asterisk is put to the argument name in the function name or to the type name for which the pointer type is referred to. The argument declarations `T* arg` and `T *arg` are identical.

Answer (score 1):

There is no differecne in the code pairs you've shown. They are same.

- `char *s`
- `char * s`
- `char* s`

all are same. *Most of the time* **extra** whitespace(s) is(are) ignored in `c`.

To clear your confusion, in case of

```
char *s
```

the `*` should be *read* as a part of the data type, it is not a part of the variable name.

IMHO, to avoid confusion , better to write `char * s;`

Comment: Then how come "String *str" and not put it as "String * str" too?

Comment: @lv23 you're most welcome to write the way you like. :-) both are correct.

Comment: Professor is playing tricks then... but thanks!

Comment: @lv23 and hope your professor in not a prt of this community. :-)